# How to append axes in Matplotlib but not inherit axis type (Cartopy type, to be specific)

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I use Basemap to plot, which doesn't introduce its own axis type and rather does some extreme math to make its geographic plotting. That let this work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(); #use instead of fig because it inits an axis too
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax); #prep to add an axis
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='2.0%', pad=0.15); #make a color bar axis
```

I preferred this because it kept the new axis within the original axis bounds, which made lining up other subplots (by using an identical `divider.append_axes(...)` call with them as well) easy and making sure the new colorbar axis didn't clip off the plot easy as well.

But since Basemap is depreciated, I'm trying to move to Cartopy. Unfortunately similar code with Cartopy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy as cartopy
fig, ax = plt.subplots(); #use instead of fig because it inits an axis too
ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree()); #redefine the axis to be a geographical axis
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax); #prep to add an axis
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='2.0%', pad=0.15); #make a color bar axis
```

Gives the error:

```
KeyError: 'map_projection'
```

Since under Cartopy the axis `ax` is changed to a Cartopy axis, the appended axis `cax` is also a Cartopy axis. If I provide a `map_projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree()` the code runs, but I don't want it to be a Cartopy axis, I want it to be a colorbar (and the Cartopy axis errors if I use it as a colorbar).

**How can I `append_axes` but not inherit the Cartopy axis type?**

Additionally, I found not-quite-good-enough work-around using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy as cartopy
fig, ax = plt.subplots(); #use instead of fig because it inits an axis too
ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree()); #redefine the axis to be a geographical axis
cax = ax.inset_axes((1.02, 0, 0.02, 1)); #make a color bar axis
```

But that `cax` is not part of the original axis bounds, which makes it useless for lining up other subplots that use the `divider.append_axes()` method and the colorbar can clip off the edge of the plot since it is floating in "white space".

Comment: "But that cax is not part of the 0-to-1 bounds of the original axis"  Can you explain what that means?  I'm also not clear on what you mean by "useless for lining up other subplots...".  Overall, it looks like you are using a pattern to line up axes that depends on the lightly maintained `append_axes`, and unfortunately cartopy is not compatible with it.  I'm sure it is possible to do what you want to do, but you may need to make some changes.

Comment: I def need to change some method; Matplotlib has a myriad of methods to accomplish a single task and I know vanishingly few. When you append an axis onto another axis using the `make_axes_locatable` method, the new axis sits inside the original axis area or 'box. (I checked, its not 0-to-1 coords, just takes up original axis space) `insert` makes an axis that floats and can clip off the plot. It would make lining up with non-Cartopy subplots that use `make_axes_locatable` easy. I am low-key hoping there is a special `kwargg` for `append_axes` that can specify what type of axis to generate.

Comment: Suggest using inset_axes and constrained_layout to line things up.  But without more code to see what you are trying to do, it’s hard to advise further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52447676/21257881:

```
import matplotlib.axes as maxes
cax = divider.append_axes("top", size="5%", axes_class=maxes.Axes)
```